# Installation failed in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I get this error message again and again when i try to run the android application on the emulator.

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: F:\PSL2.0\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

EDIT: The project was devepoped on my project teammate's computer and giving this error on my pc, may be that's why its not working!

Comment: do you have an older apk of the app in your emulator?

Comment: @suraj no, I dont.

Comment: wipe out data of emulator and run again

Comment: @AnandSavjani still not working..

Comment: delete that emulator and create a new one for solution

Comment: @AnandSavjani ame error again even after creating a new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "Clean Build" from the Android Studio build options menu.
2. Open a command prompt (Windows key + enter 'cmd' + Enter in Windows) and type `adb kill-server`, hit return, and then `adb start-server`, return
3. If it still doesn't work, restart Android Studio, delete the emulator and create a new AVD

Answer (score 0):

unchecked this option::settings>build,execute,deployment>instant run>Enable instant run to hot swap code /resource change on deploy

Answer (score 0):

Disable instant run in settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Instant run and disable it!