# Application installation failed even after reviewing everything clearly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

Seems my Android studios isn't working as it used to work before.

When I run the emulator, it loads for a bit of time, later it opens the emulator, but the project isn't loading up. I'm receiving strange type of error:

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\google-services-master\android...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I had some thoughs maybe the project is broken, so I made a new one. The same problem occurs, I created a new emulator, didn't helped either, rebuilded and cleaned the project and still receiving the same problem.

I've checked these topics:
[Installation failed in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318676/installation-failed-in-android-studio)

[Android Studio: Application Installation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718044/android-studio-application-installation-failed)

Couldn't fix it either.. Idk, maybe I should reinstall Android Studios? But hell yeah, it takes so long to install all the updates..

P.S. The project consumes only 1 layout and 1 imageview.

Everything was working fine until now..

Comment: According to the error message, your emulator has an old version of the app installed, you can just press Yes when it asks you to uninstall the existing app.

Comment: I did that few times, it only displays another error in the log cat..
Session &#39;app&#39;: Error Installing APKs

Following Run time error..:

DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Error while installing APKs.

Well, Ill probably try to install Android again

Comment: No doubts, android studios is pretty misterious..